# Using date_popup as a Month picker and not individual days

Tags: php, jquery, drupal-7, datepicker, drupal-forms

I've been google'n my tail off with no luck.

I'm currently using the date_popup on my form in Drupal 7, but the users submitting the form don't have individual dates to submit. Their tags only show a month/year but then the form is asking for a date also. Normally I'd say they could figure it out, but you would be amazed how many emails I've gotten from confused users. I've changed it to

```
$form['made_on_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#title' => t('Manufacture Date'),
    '#date_format' => 'Y-m',
    '#date_year_range' => '-100:+0',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="can_float">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

which removed the date from the field once clicked, but you still have to click on a day within the month for it to close the popup.

Is there a way to change the type to only show Month and Year in the selection popup?
I'm using this through the Date module with Drupal 7.

I already tried `'#type' => 'month_popup',` but surprise surprise that didn't work. If only. ha

Answer (score 0):

I don't think date_popup comes with an option to do this (it's mainly javascript). If it's just about selecting a month: why don't you use a simple select list or 'date_select'?

With "date_select":

```
$form["month_and_year"] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_select',
    '#date_timezone' => date_default_timezone(),    
    '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()),                                     
    '#date_format' => 'm.Y',                                                
);
```

Or with a simple select list:

```
$form["just_month"] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(
        1 => t("Jan"),
        2 => t("Feb"),
        ...
    ),
);
```

Comment: I had already set it up with a date_select for the short term, but they're really hung up on having a fancy popup box for the selector. Thanks for the quick reply though!